# How to do p4 (perforce) merge using command line?

Tags: perforce

I am writing a batch script on windows for p4 merging.

In p4, I have a source and destination folder as follows:

> **source     :** //depot/a/b/c/src/
>
> **destination:** //depot/a/b/c/dest/

All I want is to replace the entire content of "dest" with "src".

So, before merging if source looks like this:

> src/Folder1/1.txt (content is 1111)
>
> src/Folder1/2.txt (content is 2222)
>
> src/Folder2/1.txt (content is 3333)
>
> src/Folder2/2.txt (content is 4444)

and before merging, dest looks like this:

> dest/Folder1/1.txt (content is 5555)
>
> dest/Folder1/3.txt (content is 6666)
>
> dest/Folder4/1.txt (content is 7777)
>
> dest/Folder4/2.txt (content is 8888)

Then, after merging, "dest" should look like this:

> dest/Folder1/1.txt (content is 1111)
>
> dest/Folder1/2.txt (content is 2222)
>
> dest/Folder2/1.txt (content is 3333)
>
> dest/Folder2/2.txt (content is 4444)

**Notice**:

*Folder4* gets ***deleted*** from dest because it was not there in src.

*Folder2* gets **added** into dest because it was there in src.

**What I am doing is:**

1. **p4 integrate //depot/a/b/c/src/... //depot/a/b/c/dest/...**
2. **p4 resolve -at**
3. **p4 submit -d "merging content from src to dest"**

But, it's not giving me desired behavior. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you say

> All I want is to replace the entire content of "dest" with "src"

you should use `p4 copy`, as in:

```
p4 copy //depot/a/b/c/src/... //depot/a/b/c/dest/...
```

See [the docs](https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r15.1/manuals/cmdref/p4_copy.html), and don't forget to `p4 submit` afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that `p4 integrate` will integrate only *previously unintegrated* changes.  If some changes were previously integrated (and altered due to merge conflicts), your `p4 integrate //depot/a/b/c/src/... //depot/a/b/c/dest/...` command will not redo them.

To clobber `dest` from `src`, I think you need to add the `-f` flag when using `p4 integrate` to ignore previous integration history (and then follow it with `p4 resolve -at` as before).

Comment: What I want is --- when I do merging from src -> dest. Then, content of src and dest should appear exactly similar.

Comment: Which means, if "dest" contains a new folder or file which was not in "src", then, it should get deleted.

Comment: That missing piece is done by `p4 copy` -- see Bryan's answer.  If you look at very old Perforce docs you can find a sequence of steps to do this manually with a combination of `p4 integ -f` and `p4 delete`, but `p4 copy` exists now and is easier.  :)